# Python raw_input not working and input bugged

Tags: python, input

Python 2.7
MacOS Sierra

Sorry, about the title being vague I really didn't know how to explain my issue. I just don't know what is wrong with my code. The problem is in the start1() function I want to make it so you enter some of the input and if you accidentally hit enter while this is asking you then just rerun the function.

```
def start1():
    os.system('clear');
    print("---------------------------");
    os.system('clear')
    if (PlayerIG.XP >= PlayerIG.MaxXP):
        LevelUP();
    print "Name:", PlayerIG.name
    print "XP: ", PlayerIG.XP, "/", PlayerIG.MaxXP
    print "Attack:", PlayerIG.Attack
    print "Health:", PlayerIG.Health;
    print "Gold:", PlayerIG.Gold

    print("1) Adventure");
    print("2) Store");
    print("3) Rest");
    print("4) Save");
    print("5) Exit");

    option = input('-->');
    if (option == 1):
        prefight();
    elif (option == 2):
        store();
    elif (option == 3):
        Rest();
    elif (option == 4):
        Save()
    elif (option == 5):
        sys.exit();
    else:
        start1()
```

if i continue using the line:
option = input('--->');

it works but when i accidentaly hit enter early or do anything other then the numbers shown it doesn't run the else statement but passes an Error:

unexpected EOF while parsing

I looked into this error and it is something to do with Input(). So when i attempt to use raw_input('--->'); Which i do wanted to do from the start. it just restarts the Start1() Function. the Start1() function being the code onscreen

Comment: `int(raw_input())`

Comment: Never use `input()` in Python 2. If you need to convert the result of `raw_input()`, do that, as in `int(raw_input())`.

Comment: Also, don't _ever_ use `input` in python2. It's blasphemy.

Comment: Your indentation is totally off.

Comment: Sorry about the indent! I'm new to SO and that was the first time i tried to paste my code so it messed up and i was stupid enough not to actually read the code right. I was very unclear about my issue in my question see if i do int(raw_input()) the else can't work if the option variable is a string. the idea is for the menu to load you answer with the corresponding number and it runs! but if you hit enter without the number the answer is equal too ''. which isn't an int so i get the error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: Essentially i think i need the input to work as a string and an int